munin plugin memory: graph draws the wrong total memory
I've got a server running on a kvm based server with ubuntu 24.04.1.
The size of the ram is just under 8GB.
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        8082704 kB

The value from the munin plugin itself is correct:
sudo -u munin munin-run memory config
graph_args --base 1024 -l 0 --upper-limit 8276688896

But the memory graph draws 20GB!

Are there any configuration settings or something else to limit the graph?
